# Impedir quebra de página em relatório Microsoft Report

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, reportviewer

Criei um relatório no Visual Studio 2015. As informações são exibidas corretamente:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém, quando eu clico pra visualizar impressão, ele é cortado (veja que as informações que eu pintei não estão aparecendo):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como fazer pra impedir que a página seja "quebrada"?

Comment: Creio que as únicas opções são: redimensionar sua tabela; ou redimensionar o rdlc

Comment: Italo pode fazer um teste? Reduza o tamanho da sua tabela, limitando cada coluna ao mínimo necessário. Tive um problema semelhante e no meu caso como a tabela sempre ficava muito próximo as margens da página ele quebrava para a próxima página. Veja a configuração das margens também do report

Comment: oi @rodrigorf, vou fazer esse teste sim. eu já tinha desistido de usar report e comecei a aprender iTextSharp, nele eu tô desenrolando (embora que tenho que gerar tudo na mão). mas obrigado pela dica ;)

Comment: Beleza, Report as vezes frusta um pouco mas depois que as coisas começam a andar fica mais tranquilo. Espero que dê certo.

Comment: kkkk blz. no iTextSharp eu acabei de criar meu primeiro PDF. achei muito fácil de usar. Acho que vou ficar com ele por enquanto.